# Losing Uri between implicit camera intents

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

I'm putting together a camera app using implicit intents for a college assignment, and I can't figure out what's going wrong with my Uri. I'm assigning a jpg file, then opening the camera using MediaStore. ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE as shown below. When I call selectImage(), I want the chosen viewing app to go straight to my recently taken photo. However, although the photo is saved and visible within the gallery, I'm getting an "Item not found" Toast, and I'm looking at an overview of all the image folders. Where am I going wrong?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    photoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"cameraTest.jpg");
    outputFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", photoFile);
    Log.i("debugging",outputFile.getPath().toString());

}

public void capturePhoto(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFile);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(outputFile);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
        Log.i("debugging",outputFile.getPath().toString());
    }
}
public void selectImage(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Log.i("debugging",outputFile.getPath().toString());

    intent.setDataAndType(outputFile, "image/*");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119483/android-camera-photo-comes-back-null

Comment: That looks to be just what I was searching for - thanks Ivan!

Comment: It is strange that you needed that as `Log.i("debugging",outputFile.getPath().toString());` would have told you what was the case.